# Rewrite if folder doesn't exist?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /bio.php?bio=$1 [L]
```

I need it to do the following:

- Get the following rewritten URL: http://www.website.com/john-smith to go to /bio.php?bio=john-smith (that kind of works at the moment)
- If there is already a folder (eg /about-us/) then show the file in that instead. At the moment it does but it adds ?bio=about-us on the end.
- Ideally if possible work with & without the trailing slash.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bio/bio.php?q=$1 [L]
```

First line will skip the RewriteRule if it finds a matching physical file; second line will skip it if it finds a matching directory. The third line is the rewrite rule that will be executed if the preceding condtions are met.

Comment: Works a treat, thank you. Really need to sit down and master rewrites! New years resolution me thinks.